# Implementing search using custom pipe in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I tried implementing my own pipe in angular 6 using search box for filtering the list of my campaigns. Oddly, I'm unable to filter the the list of campaigns. I'm posting my code down below.

This is how my filter looks like:

```js
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'nameFilter'
})

export class NameFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: any[], key: string, value: string): any[] {
    debugger;

    if (!values) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!value) {
      return values;
    }
    return values.filter(val => val.CampaignName === value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search here">

<tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns?.result | nameFilter : searchText">

  <td style="max-width:280px">
  
    <p>{{campaign.CampaignName}}</p>
    
    <small><span class="cursor" (click)="filterByOwnr(campaign.DepartmentName)" > {{ campaign.DepartmentName }} &nbsp; &nbsp; </span></small>
    
  </td>
```

I debugged my pipe, and this is how it looks like:

[image: Debug window for pipe]

I am able to get the value to my pipe but unable to apply filter in my html page.

**P.S** : After trying @Arcteezy , i'm getting the following error.

[image]

Console log for **console.log(field)** :

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code.

Comment: @HaseebAhmed Sir, Can you please check now.

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches or if it only contains than show that as well?

Comment: I'm looking for exact match sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'filter'
    })

    @Injectable()
    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {

            console.log(value);
            if (!items) {
                return [];
            }
            if (!field || !value) {
                return items;
            }

            return items.filter(singleItem => singleItem[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
        }
    }
```

In your HTML,

```
    *ngFor = "let... | filter : '<search_field>' : searchText"
```

Comment: Sir, I'm getting the following error. I've attached a log to my question.

Comment: Sir, I've imported the @Injectable and tried to log the **value** on the console and i have attached the copy of my log above. Please look.

Comment: So value is not undefined. Do a `console.log(items.filter(singleItem => singleItem[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())))`. And this one too `console.log(items.filter(singleItem => singleItem[field].toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase()))`

Comment: I believe you are trying to filter based on CampaignName. `console.log(field)` to make sure you are getting that correct.

Comment: I did a console log of **field**. Please check the link above.

Comment: Dude, what i meant with <search_field> was you should enter the field for filtering xD. Your are searching based on campaign right? So it should be `*ngFor = "let... | filter : 'CampaignName' : searchText"`

Comment: Oh god!! I'm being super dumb here XD. Sorry man! And yes, it works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe file

```
filteredItems: Array<any>;
// Items & searchText is the input of the pipe;
// @param: Items contains current object in the ngFor loop.
// @param: searchText is the text that is need to be searched string.


transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {

    if (!items) {
        return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
        return items;
    }
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    this.filteredItems =  items.filter( function (records) {
        let searchMatched;
        for ( const keys in records ) {
            if ( typeof (records[keys]) === 'string') {
                searchMatched = records[keys].toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
                if (searchMatched) {
                    return searchMatched;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (this.filteredItems.length < Constants.ONE_COUNT) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return this.filteredItems;
    }
}
```

Returning the -1 in the last second line is to handle the zero results found.

HTML File

```
*ngFor="data| searchFilter: inputText;
```

The above code will do the case-insensitive search if you want to implement case sensitive search please remove the conversion of search text to lowercase

Answer (score 0):

in your pipe `.ts`

```
 @Pipe({
  name: 'nameFilter'
})

export class NameFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: any, key?: string): any[] {
    debugger;
    if (!key) return values;
    key = (key.trim()).toLowerCase();
    return values.filter(val => (val.CampaignName).toLowerCase() === key);
  }
}
```

and in your `.html`

```
<tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns | nameFilter : searchText">
```

here is a link of working example of [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-takwdb)